# How to get issue type in YouTrack workflow

Tags: workflow, youtrack

I want to make a workflow script that will template the issue depending on the type of issue.
Now my script looks like this, but it doesn't work, what could be the problem?

```
var workflow = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/workflow');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  title: workflow.i18n('Insert default description template for external users'),
  guard: function(ctx) {
    var issue = ctx.issue;
    return !issue.isReported && !issue.becomesReported && issue.description === null;
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
    var issue = ctx.issue;
    
    if(issue.fields.becomes(ctx.Type, ctx.Type.Bug))
      {
        ctx.issue.description = workflow.i18n("### **Initial state:**") +
        "\n\n" +
        workflow.i18n('### **Steps to reproduce:**') +
        "\n1.\n2.\n3.\n\n" +
        workflow.i18n("### **Expectations:**") +
        "\n\n" +
        workflow.i18n("### **Actual:**") +
        "\n";
      }
    if(issue.fields.becomes(ctx.Type, ctx.Type.Task))
      {
        ctx.issue.description = workflow.i18n("### **Some text:**");
      }
    if(issue.fields.becomes(ctx.Type, ctx.Type.Feature))
      {
        ctx.issue.description = workflow.i18n("### **Some text:**");
      }
    
  },
  requirements: {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Type should be specified in the requirements if you want to pass it as a parameter like that. Otherwise, you just specify an object that doesn't exist, hence it throws an exception.

You can learn more about what's included in context (ctx) and how it works here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/context.html

Comment: I read this, but only today I realized how the context works with EnumField. Thank you, Sergey, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Can you share how you have achieved it Stanislaw

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `issue.fields.Type.name`, so you have to adjust your condition to `ctx.issue.Type.name == "Bug"`, etc.

Sample condition for specific types:

```
return ["User Story", "Task", "Bug"].indexOf(ctx.issue.fields.Type.name) != -1;
```